# Power BI - Count using multiple columns

Tags: powerbi, dax

My dataset includes 2 columns :-

Disabledx - a calculated text column contain Yes and No values 
Deletedx - a calculated text column contain Yes and No values

Is it possible to have a measure that counts records where Disabledx = Yes AND Deletedx = "No"?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try below code:-

```
Measure =
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( 'table' ),
    FILTER ( 'table', 'table'[Disabledx] = "Yes" && 'table'[Deletedx] = "No" )
)
```